# The local variable may not have been initialized error

Tags: java, eclipse

i have fixed it now, but it still shows me 0 after i input my first numbers. it shows me correct on vikt but not in pris. :S

```
package Brev;

import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

public class Uppgift1 {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        String indata = showInputDialog("Hur mycket väger ditt brev i gram?");

        int vikt = Integer.parseInt(indata);
        int pris = 0;

        do {

            indata = showInputDialog("Ditt porto kostar " + pris + " kr med vikten " + vikt + " Gram." +
                    "\nSkriv in en följande vikt för att addera på ditt nuvarande porto.");

            vikt = vikt + Integer.parseInt(indata);



            pris = pris + pris;




        if (vikt < 1) {

            showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
        }

        else if (vikt <= 50){


            showMessageDialog(null, "Portot blir "+ (pris + 7) + "Kr. med " + vikt + " Gram.");
        }

        else if (vikt <= 100){


            showMessageDialog(null, "Portot blir "+ (pris + 14) + "Kr. med " + vikt + " Gram.");
        }

        else if (vikt <= 250){


            showMessageDialog(null, "Portot blir "+ (pris + 28) + "Kr. med " + vikt + " Gram.");
        }

        else if (vikt <= 500){


            showMessageDialog(null, "Portot blir "+ (pris + 42) + "Kr. med " + vikt + " Gram.");
        } 

        else if (vikt <= 1000){


            showMessageDialog(null, "Portot blir "+ (pris + 56) + "Kr. med " + vikt + " Gram.");
        }

        else if (vikt <= 2000){


            showMessageDialog(null, "Portot blir "+ (pris + 70) + "Kr. med " + vikt + " Gram.");
        }

        else if (vikt > 2000)

            showMessageDialog(null, "Maximalvikten är 2000GRAM / 2KG");




        } while (vikt <= 2000);





    }
}
```

Comment: What value do you want `pris` to have? You never set a value...

Comment: Set  `pris=0` before loop and start adding it up with whatever value you want. If you don't do so `pris + pris` will always give you ZERO.

Comment: I want the value of pris to be 0 hexafraction. 

Aramiti you are thinking good that's what i want to. but if i write "int pris = 0;" same thing happens.

Comment: Once you set `int pris = 0;`, you **don't** get an uninitialized error anymore. So that error is unrelated to other problems you may have here. Maybe you should use a different title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing code that looks ambiguous:

```
"aString" + anInt + anotherInt + "anotherString"
```

Java is interpreting this to mean the equivalent of:

```
("aString" + anInt) + anotherInt + "anotherString"
```

so that each `int` is converted to a `String` before being added, but you wanted to do the equivalent of:

```
"aString" + (anInt + anotherInt) + "anotherString"
```

So, just write it in this last, unambiguous way. Put parentheses around your math formulas if they're part of a string addition.

Comment: I have fixed it but it stills shows me 0 on "pris" after first number input and "vikt" is correct.

Comment: @AihamAl-salehy ask another question then

Comment: @AihamAl-salehy 0 + 0 = 0. That's not even really a programming question.